# Android disable Camera2 auto focus while recording a video

Tags: android, video, blur, android-camera2, autofocus

I have been recording a video using Camera2 API on android. The problem that I am facing is when I look carefully at the recorded video, after about 3-4 seconds in, the video appears like the camera was trying to focus. It looks blur sometimes and sometimes very clear. Now, I am not very sure if this is due to auto-focus or auto-exposure or something else. So I tried the following ways in order to disable the intermittent blurring of the recorded video. I did this configuration for both, the recorder surface as well as the preview surface. Below is the code I am using.

```
 /** Requests used for preview only in the [CameraCaptureSession] */
    private val previewRequest: CaptureRequest by lazy {
        // Capture request holds references to target surfaces
        cameraCaptureSession.device.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW).apply {
            // Add the preview surface target
            // viewFinder.holder.setFixedSize(videoSize?.width!!, videoSize?.height!!)
            addTarget(viewFinder.holder.surface)

            // code of your interest
            set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL)
            set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF)
            set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF)
            set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_ANTIBANDING_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_ANTIBANDING_MODE_OFF)
            set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_CANCEL)
        }.build()
    }

    /** Requests used for preview and recording in the [CameraCaptureSession] */
    private val recordRequest: CaptureRequest by lazy {
        // Capture request holds references to target surfaces
        cameraCaptureSession.device.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD).apply {
            // Add the preview and recording surface targets
            addTarget(viewFinder.holder.surface)
            addTarget(recorderSurface)
            // Sets user requested FPS for all targets
            // set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, Range(args.fps, args.fps))
            set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, Range(0, 0))

            // code of your interest
            set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL)
            set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF)
            set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF)
            set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_ANTIBANDING_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_ANTIBANDING_MODE_OFF)
            set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_CANCEL)
        }.build()
    }
```

None of the above config. fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, the issue you are having is that when you are recording, the camera will zoom in and out.

I had the same issue in the past and the following step helped me.

Try to remove this code in recording block:

```
set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL)
set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF)
set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF)
set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_ANTIBANDING_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_ANTIBANDING_MODE_OFF)
set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_CANCEL)
```

And replace it with the following one:

```
set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO)
```